# Sub classing TTask in XE7: E2251 Ambiguous overloaded call to 'Create'

Tags: multithreading, delphi, inheritance, overriding

I want to add some functionality to ITask/TTask. I wrapped the new methods in a new Interface (IMyTask) which inherits from ITask:

```
type

  IMyTask = interface(ITask)
    procedure MyNewMethod;
  end;

  TMyTask = class(TTask, ITask, IMyTask)
    private
      FSomeList: TList<integer>;
    public
      procedure MyNewMethod;

      constructor Create(const AProc: TProc; AThreadPool: TThreadPool = nil); overload;
      constructor Create(Sender: TObject; Event: TNotifyEvent); overload;
      constructor Create(const Proc: TProc); overload;
      constructor Create(Sender: TObject; Event: TNotifyEvent; const APool: TThreadPool); overload;

  end;
```

My class contains members that should be initialized in its constructor (for example FSomeList). So calling my constructor is mandatory. In the same time I didn't want to change the implementation of Create(). So I re declared Create() as constructor with four overrides.
But creating an instance of TMyTask fails to compile with E2251:

```
procedure TestCreateMyTask;
var
  i: IMyTask;
begin
  i := TMyTask.Create(  // --> E2251 Ambiguous overloaded call to 'Create'
    procedure
    begin
    end
  );
end;
```

I tried with "Reintroduce" keyword but it seems not to work may be because all Create() methods are marked with "Overload".

How to overcome this problem?

**UPDATE:**

Further tests resulted in two QCs:

- [**QC129032:** Using TTask.WaitForAll() causes a deadlock](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=129032)
- [**QC129032:** ITask.Cancel does not process complete events](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=129033)

Comment: This looks all wrong but it's hard for us to say what is right without knowing what you want to achieve. It's clear why your code fails to compile. The error message says it all.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan why wrong? I clearly described my goal?

Comment: @David, what is obvious on that compilation failure ? The second variant should have been chosen. I can see no ambiguity here.

Comment: @TLama You are ignoring the methods in the base class

Comment: I don't know what your goal is. Perhaps remove all the Create methods and write `TMyTask.Create(...) as IMyTask` perhaps. But I'm guessing.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My goal is to add some functionality to ITask/TTask via my custom interface. What's wrong with this???

Comment: Nobody said anything was wrong. I just cannot tell precisely what you want. Never mind. I'll guess.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I missed my own constructor. I did edit my question (code and explanation). You may want to edit your answer...

Comment: And now the question changes!! Why didn't you trust me when I asked you for more?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you noticed before I clicked "Add Comment" :)

Comment: I should not have bothered here. I regret getting involved here. I tried to help and you told me that there was enough information in the question. And then you decided that no, there was more that you had not told us. Sigh.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan after the third comment I re read my question a few more times and saw there was something wrong. I edited it and notified you very polite. Obviously I need more time to think than you expect. You're getting angry too fast. Sorry.

Comment: OK. I've updated the answer as best I can. I'm not angry. Just frustrated. No problems.

Comment: And now I've deleted the answer. As I surmised, this class is not intended to be derived from. I'm sure Allen can help you far better than I can.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you feel you should create a TTask descendant? You should not create a TTask descendant except in very rare circumstances. The better solution is to use a regular task within another object.

The Create methods on TTask aren't actually constructors, rather they're static class functions. The reason for this is to ensure that you only ever work with an ITask and not the TTask directly. You also cannot construct a TTask with the default parameter-less constructor (it raises an exception). The source even has a comment near that constructor

```
  constructor Create; overload; // do not call this constructor!!
```

The difference between the "Create" functions and the "Run" functions is whether or not the task is scheduled. Run will return a task already scheduled into the thread pool. Create will defer that to when the caller decides to schedule it.

```
  class function Create(Sender: TObject; Event: TNotifyEvent): ITask; overload; static; inline;
  class function Create(const Proc: TProc): ITask; overload; static; inline;
  class function Create(Sender: TObject; Event: TNotifyEvent; const APool: TThreadPool): ITask; overload; static; inline;
  class function Create(const Proc: TProc; APool: TThreadPool): ITask; overload; static; inline;
  class function Run(Sender: TObject; Event: TNotifyEvent): ITask; overload; static; inline;
  class function Run(Sender: TObject; Event: TNotifyEvent; APool: TThreadPool): ITask; overload; static; inline;
  class function Run(const Func: TProc): ITask; overload; static; inline;
  class function Run(const Func: TProc; APool: TThreadPool): ITask; overload; static; inline;
```

As I said, it is better to simply use the TTask Create or Run methods directly and not create a descendant. If you want to encapsulate the task's operations, feel free to create your own class type and internally create and schedule the task(s).

Comment: One of the reasons for descending was that Cancel() does not notify for Task's completion. So WaitForAll/WaitForAny do block even if a task is cancelled i.e. ran to completion.

Comment: The only reason I did subclass from TTask is to overcome some limitations that it has (for now). This fails under the "rare circumstances" that you mentioned.

Comment: For example: I want to create a TTaskList class that is itself a TTask (i.e. descends from TTask). This gives me the opportunity add other TTaskLists in it i.e. I'll be able to chain complex tasks. Also ITask does not offer native way to add CompleteEvent handlers neither has DoneEvent exposed. BTW I dream of System.Threading.IEvent to be publicly available, for example in SyncObjs. IInterface based event is very useful in TTask projects.

Comment: And lastly, but also important: ITask does not offer continuations.

Comment: Continuations are internally implemented, however they came in too late to fully expose them. They are on the list for a future release. Cancel should notify completion... if not it's a bug. Please enter a bug at http://quality.embarcadero.com.

Comment: Thank you for the information. In fact I posted two QCs: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=129032 and http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=129033