# How to store data in TTask instance for later use?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

My goal is to store some data (TValue) in a TTask instance before I run it and later use it from within the task. I want to use anonymous handlers instead of TNotifyEvent ones.

Something like this:

```
LTask.SetData(LMyData);
```

and later use it like this:

```
LSomeData := TTask.CurrentTask.GetData();
```

So the data can be accessed via Task's instance.

I was thinking about inheriting from TTask, [but it's tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27082469/1022219) and may be not the best option.

Is there any other way of storing data into TTask, using RTTI or something else?

I use Delphi 10 Seattle.

Comment: Use variable capture